# Infinity Width Pushes Frame Off Screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Basically I have a picture that is supposed to stretch the entire width of the screen, but when I fix the width to infinity - it pushes the frame width off the screen - like shown below.

[image]

Minimum Reproducible Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            //Grey background color
            Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            
            VStack {
                
                Image("PS5")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 250)

 
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        
    }
}

struct ItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ItemView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You gave `aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` so it fills proportionally according to specified `height`. What's wrong? What would you expect?

Comment: Maybe my modifiers are wrong then - I want the photo to fit inside the entire width of the screen (not greater than the width) with a specified height and I don't care if it distorts the image. What would be the proper modifiers then?

Answer (score 0):

... follow-up on comments - just delete `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` to have

```
Image("PS5")
    .resizable()
    .frame(height: 250)
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting - what's the default aspect ratio?